# How to migrate from Sybase PowerBuilder V6.0 or V7.0 to Sybase PowerBuilder V12.0, either classic or .NET, and convert it to a web application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, sybase, powerbuilder-conversion

How to migrate from Sybase PowerBuilder V6.0 or V7.0 to Sybase PowerBuilder V12.0, either classic or .NET, and convert it to a web application?

How to transform the converted PowerBuilder V12.0 project to a web application project to host and run it in a web server (Windows server 2003/IIS V6.0/ASP.NET V4.0)?

What are the supported and unsupported features when converting from a desktop to a web application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found that in the Sybase website but not in details and no examples are shown.**